# Prevent text from wrapping under the input field

Tags: html, css

I have card with Input and some text wrapped in span right to it. When text is long it wraps under the checkbox

Codepen: http://codepen.io/padmacnu/pen/bpKOVB

```css
div {
  font: 12px arial;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  border: 1px solid #111111;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span>text is too long and wraps under the checkbox</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried white-space: nowrap;

Comment: Where do you want text to go? The div is not big enough for that amount of text.

Comment: `display:flex;` on your div will place them both in the same row

Comment: besides the point, but you should really use a `label` in stead of a span

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this: http://codepen.io/dirtysmith/pen/QNxzGM

```
div {
  font: 12px arial;

  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  border: 1px solid #111111;
}
input{
    width:20px;

    position:relative;
    left: 0px; 

    vertical-align:middle; 
}

span{  
    width:200px;       

    position:relative;
    left: 0px;

    display:inline-block;    
    vertical-align:middle; 
}
```

Comment: +1 for a backwards compatible-solution... flex is a cool piece of CSS, but not great for older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can float the input and make the `span` a block which establishes a block formatting context.

```css
div {
  font: 12px arial;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  border: 1px solid #111111;
}
input {
  float: left;
}
span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden; /* Establish BFC */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>text is too long and wraps under the checkbox text is too long and wraps under the checkbox</span>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use flexbox:

```css
div {
  font: 12px arial;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  border: 1px solid #111111;
  display: flex;
}
span {
  flex: 1; /* Fill remaining space left by the input */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>text is too long and wraps under the checkbox text is too long and wraps under the checkbox</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Members for the quick helpful response :)

Answer (score 0):

1. float: left on the input worked
2. Flex also worked like charm

```css
div {
  font: 12px arial;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  border: 1px solid #111111;
}
input {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>text is too long and wraps under the checkbox</span>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/padmacnu/pen/bpKOVB